# "You wouldn't say bad about a team you belong, would you?"

Tags: emotion

Is the phrase "you wouldn't say bad about a team you belong, would you?" a form of  manipulation? Does this type of manipulation have a specific name/term?

Comment: Can you give a link about the definition of manipulation?

Comment: I closed this question because to me it feels like it's asking to judge whether a particular person, who used this phrase, is being manipulative or not. That's simply not something we can address here. Further, we require questions be somehow framed in psychology and neuroscience: we need some referenced connection to what you already know and what has prompted the question for it to be answerable here. See: https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2277/why-was-my-question-closed-as-not-framed-in-psychology-or-neuroscience

Comment: @BryanKrause You should read it again then, since I don't mention anyone in any form whatsoever. Anyway... my fault this is just not the correct forum to ask which is a shame.